# Problems accessing specific list item

Tags: python, list, indexoutofrangeexception

I thought I was reasonably good with python, but this problem has stumped me.

The following code works

```
import csv
f = open("potholes.csv")
count = 0
for row in csv.DictReader(f):
    addr_bits = row['STREET ADDRESS'].split()

    street_num = addr_bits[0:1]
    count += 1
print type(addr_bits)
print addr_bits
print street_num
print "completed processing " + str(count) + " records"
```

OUTPUT:

```
<type 'list'>
['2519', 'S', 'HALSTED', 'ST']
['2519']
completed processing 378033 records
```

This code however gives an error

```
import csv
f = open("potholes.csv")
count = 0
for row in csv.DictReader(f):
    addr_bits = row['STREET ADDRESS'].split()

    street_num = addr_bits[0]
    count += 1
print type(addr_bits)
print addr_bits
print street_num
print "completed processing " + str(count) + " records"
```

OUTPUT:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linux/PycharmProjects/potholes/potholes", line 7, in <module>
    street_num = addr_bits[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The only difference is that the first code used [0:1] to access this list the second piece used [0], but I thought that was legal way of accessing a list.

Comment: If `thing[0]` is an `IndexError`, then `thing` is zero length. `thing[:1]` (`0` is the default start) will still work, but will also be zero length; `[][:1] == []`.

Comment: You have an empty line, use `if addr_bits:street_num  = addr_bits[0]`, they both also return different things so the code is not comparable, the first returns a list slice the second a single element so even without the error your code is not the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that's because sometimes row['STREET ADDRESS'] is empty making `row['STREET ADDRESS'].split()` return an empty list

and you can access empty lists with slices but not index specific element.

here is an example:

```
In [10]: x = []

In [11]: x[0:1] # this returns empty list
Out[11]: []

In [12]: x[0] # this will raise an error
```

Comment: Thank you, I have added a try / except and it is now working. I will accept this as the answer as soon as I am able to.

Comment: i would have done `len(x)>0` instead of try and except,  its a bit cleaner

Comment: @DorElias note that `if len(x) > 0:` is usually just written `if x:` cleaner still!